# Leer Array e imprimirlo en HTML

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo un array En base de datos que lo almacene de la siguiente manera

```
["valor1","valor2"]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para traerlo solo hago un select con eloquent y me trae toda la información. de toda la fila que quiero.

Quisiera saber como puedo imprimir solo valor1 o valor2

lo intente de la siguiente manera

```
{{$valor->valor[1]}}
```

pero me imprime solamente `"`

Comment: `$valor[0];` ???? La verdad es dificil saber como en realidad cargas el array si no se vee el codigo.

Comment: @Excorpion ese array esta en la base de datos de esa manera. lo quiero imprimir en un pdf

Comment: Que sucede si en la vista sólo pones `{{$valor->valor}}`?

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ solo se muestra `["valor1","valor2"]`

Comment: Entonces es un string y no un array. Tendrías que hacerle un `json_decode` para pasarlo a un array https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Si lo intente pero me arroja un error de `Array to string conversion` aunque le ponga `json_decode($variable, true)`

Comment: Claro, es que no puedes imprimir directamente un array en el html. Tendrás que iterar sobre los elementos e imprimir uno por uno. Algo así `@foreach(json_decode($variable, true) as $key => $val) 
    {{$val}}
@endforeach`

Comment: @cesg.dav dado que estas utilizando laravel y eloquent lo mejor es que utilices el casting del modelo ejemplo: `protected $casts = [ 'nombre_columna' => 'array', ];` esto hará que al recuperar la fila de la base de datos automáticamente tengas un array en PHP de esa columna. Estaría bien que describieras un poco tu tabla y como tienes el modelo

Answer (score 0):

Según lo que hablamos en los comentarios, en `$valor->valor` tienes un string con este valor `["valor1","valor2"]` y no un array php.
Entonces, lo primero sería decodificar el string de JSON en un array, lo cuál puedes lograrlo con [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

Luego tendrás que iterar sobre el array resultante para imprimir los valores que tiene en cada elemento, ya que no puedes imprimir directamente un array php en el html.
Entonces creo que lo puedes resolver con un código así en la vista:

```
@foreach(json_decode($valor->valor, true) as $key => $val)      
    {{$val}} 
@endforeach
```